# set value of simple_form select dropdown with has more than one option with the same value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

My code currently looks like this:

```
<%= f.input(:l_duty,
               :required => true,
               :label => 'Weight Class',
               :collection => {"GVWR of 8,500 pounds or less" => true, "GVWR of more than 8,500 pounds" => false, "Neighborhood Electric Vehicle" => true},
               :input_html => {
                       :value => :collection[@vehicle.category], #?????????
                       :class => "span10"
                }) %>
```

And I need to be able to select the `:value` based on the key in the `:collection`, not the value. `@vehicle.l_duty` always selects `Neighborhood Electric Vehicle` when it's set to true. I have also have `@vehicle.category` which correlates to the keys in the `:collection` hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up selecting the correct field with javascript:

```
if ($('#standard_vehicle_l_duty :selected').html() == "Neighborhood Electric Vehicle" && "<%= @vehicle.category %>" != "NEV") {
  $('#standard_vehicle_l_duty option:nth-child(2)').prop('selected', true);
}
```

Not very elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question, but is seems to me that you don't need the value of you hash. In that case, simply pass an array instead of hash:

```
<%= f.input(:l_duty,
           :required => true,
           :label => 'Weight Class',
           :collection => ["GVWR of 8,500 pounds or less", "GVWR of more than 8,500 pounds", "Neighborhood Electric Vehicle"],
           :input_html => {
                   :value => @vehicle.l_duty,
                   :class => "span10"
            }) %>
```

Comment: I can't change the collection to an array.

Comment: @thatmiddleway - why can't you?

Comment: because it needs to be lined up that way to work properly with the models we have in place